# Feature Selection for Text Classification in Python

Tags: python, text, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a text classification problem in python using Random Forests from the scikit-learn library. I would like to try different features selection methods, such as Information Gain (IG) or Bi-Normal Separation (BNS), as described in this [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P/P09/P09-1078.pdf).

It seems that the only available feature selection methods available in scikit for feature selection (using the CountVectorizer class), is based on document frequency. Are other methods available in other libraries?

Comment: Try python library TextFeatureSelection. It has implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature-selection module with has tools to do univariate selection or recursive feature elimination: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_selection.html  There is no information gane or BNS in scikit-learn. Document frequency is not a feature selection method.

Comment: Yes, it seems they have not been implemented. In the end I have decided to implement BNS myself, and when I'll have some spare time I'll try to add it to the scikit library. Actually document frequency is a feature selection method, at least in the text classification domain. In that case you select the features (words) which appear in the highest number of documents.

Comment: There's a `python` library for feature selection 
`TextFeatureSelection`.  This library provides discriminatory power in the form of score for each word token. 
Those who are aware of feature selection methods in machine learning, it is based on *wrapper method* and provides ML engineers required tools to improve the classification accuracy in their NLP and deep learning models. It has 4 methods namely **Chi-square**, **Mutual information**, **Proportional difference** and **Information gain** to help select words as features before being fed into machine learning classifiers.